# Как сделать выгрузку MySQL в тестовый файл?

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте, нужно реализовать выгрузку с таблицы MySQL в тестовый файл.

То есть у меня есть таблица к примеру со строкой email.

Как сделать к примеру кнопку на сайте, чтоб скачать все email с таблицы mysql в тестовый файл ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Делается элементарно с использованием [SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html)

Comment: На SO на немалое количество вопросов можно дать ответ "делается элементарно". Проблема только в том, что не для всех одно и то же может быть элементарным. Думаю, полноценный пример в ответе был бы лучше. А ещё ответ благополучно оказался в очереди "Сообщения низкого качества", что тоже неспроста.

Comment: Вопрос должен был там оказаться. В сабже один вопрос (о запросе в MySQL), в тексте совсем другой (о создании кнопки на сайте). Напишите автору ответ с примером. Авось он не начнёт спрашивать, куда его в код веб-страницы вставлять..

Comment: Забыл про волшебную "кнопку на сайте", пардон. Я имел в виду пример полноценного SQL-запроса, а не кода кнопки. И таки нет, спасибо: я как 4 часа назад не хотел связываться с этим вопросом, так до сих пор и не хочу. Уж больно мутным он мне кажется. Но, согласитесь, в текущем виде ваш ответ тянет только на комментарий.

Comment: Наверное. Но удалять его и перемещать текст в комментарий тупо лень.